# Macports exclusion list

Tags: dependencies, macports

Is there any way to tell Macports to never install certain ports? For example, I never need the apache2 or python* ports installed but so many ports list these as dependencies when they are really not needed at all. Can I list these ports in a file somewhere that will force Macports to ignore these dependencies no matter what it thinks is best?

Comment: If they are listed as deps how would they not be needed?

Comment: Macports is sort of dumb on this point AFAIK since no port depends on any defacto library. It always assumes that any library it needs must come from the port tree. I don't need apache2 installed to use PhpDocumentor. I may just switch to Homebrew.

Comment: Ahh thats why i like it. I prefer not to have anything built against the existing system libs - i actually want a completely isolated installation of those tools. But, with regard to your question - there is no way to link against the pre-installed  libraries without doing manual installations. I think you can pass options to `configure` through `port install` but at that point it kind of defeats the purpose. If you like this behavior, hen yes id switch to homebrew.